# Lists are the same but not considered equal?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, equality

novice at Python encountering a problem testing for equality.  I have a list of lists, states[]; each state contains x, in this specific case x=3, Boolean values.  In my program, I generate a list of Boolean values, the first three of which correspond to a state[i].  I loop through the list of states testing for equality (one of them is certainly correct as all possible boolean permutations are in states, but equality is never detected.  No clue why, here is some code I modified to test it:

```
 temp1 = []
 for boolean in aggregate:
     temp1.append(boolean)
 if len(temp1) == len(propositions):
    break
 print temp1
 print states[0]
 if temp1 == states[0]:
     print 'True'
 else:
     print 'False'
```

In this case, the length of propisitons is 3.  The output I get from this code is:

```
[True, True, True]
(True, True, True)
False
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the difference in brackets?  Something to do with the fact that states[0] is a list within a list?  Cheers.

Comment: `states[0]` is a tuple, not a list. Brace/parens flavors matter very much in Python.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  I had used a built-in function to populate states and did not know that function created tuples and not lists; I didn't even know of tuples.  Thanks, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are comparing a **tuple** `(True, True, True)` against a **list** `[True, True, True]`

Of course they're different.

**Try casting your `list` to `tuple` on-the-go, to compare:**

```
temp1 = []
for boolean in aggregate:
    temp1.append(boolean)
if len(temp1) == len(propositions):
   break
print temp1
print states[0]
if tuple(temp1) == states[0]:
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

**Or casting your `tuple` to `list` on-the-go, to compare:**

```
temp1 = []
for boolean in aggregate:
    temp1.append(boolean)
if len(temp1) == len(propositions):
   break
print temp1
print states[0]
if temp1 == list(states[0]):
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

**Output:**

```
[True, True, True]
(True, True, True)
True
```

Comment: I used a built-in function to populate states[], didn't know that they were being made tuples; I've never even used tuples before, will have to read up on them, thanks very much.

Comment: @Bergy24 I'm glad my answer helped. Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)